# Adopt or create new design system

Tags: design-system, pattern-library

Would it be a best practice to recreate a new design library made of only components we used or just use this big library? The team bought a design system library in Figma that is comprehensive but we do not use all the components. We had to make adjustments to some components and add a couple new ones that we need. What has worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

Hi and welcome to StackExchange UX!

The answer depends on whether your design system exists purely in Figma, or whether the components are (or will be) representing the front-end code repository of components that your engineers use to create the production application(s).

Because it's far harder to create and change components in the code base, if your design library in Figma has no controlled relationship to that code base (probably in the form of design tokens), then you can just do what you want. But that's not a "design system" in any real sense, it's just a library of things. What happens in production will be (probably increasingly) separate over time.

Similarly with unused components: logic would suggest you'd only have things in your library that actually existed for use in the code base (or as specs for things that are being added to that code base).

I hope that goes some way to answering your question.

Comment: 100% agree with this